# URL: что означает yandsearch?

Tags: url, php

Есть URL. Для примера

```
http://yandex.by/yandsearch?text=1234567
```

В этом URL что означает "yandsearch" - какую функцию для php оно играет?
Я так понимаю, это не связанно с файловой системой.

Comment: > какую функцию для php

Никакой. Это приложение, написанное на том или ином языке, решает, как ему реагировать на такой запрос. В данном случае приложение видит, что запрошен урл yandsearch с get-параметром text и решает, какой ему код выполнять на основе этого.

> Я так понимаю это не связанно с файловой системой

Обычно все запросы к сайту скидываются на т.н. front-controller - один файл, который подключает файлы приложения, которое уже разбирается, что ему показывать. Таким образом никакого yandsearch на диске сервера, скорее всего, действительно нет.

Comment: Где я могу об этом читать подробнее? Если не сложно, киньте ссылочки!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, оно вообще не связано напрямую с файловой системой. Например, в Apache есть такая штука, как mod_rewrite, которая позволяет переопределять обработку адресов. Либо же yandsearch может быть просто папкой с файлом index.php в корне (в качестве примера, имя и расширение индексного файла может быть другим).